# python3: how to print groupby.last()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, python-3.7

```
$ cat n2.txt
apn,date
3704-156,11/04/2019
3704-156,11/22/2019
5515-004,10/23/2019
3732-231,10/07/2019
3732-231,11/15/2019

$ python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 25 2019, 10:52:18) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> df = pd.read_csv("n2.txt")
>>> df
        apn        date
0  3704-156  11/04/2019
1  3704-156  11/22/2019
2  5515-004  10/23/2019
3  3732-231  10/07/2019
4  3732-231  11/15/2019
>>> g = df.groupby('apn')
>>> g.last()
                date
apn                 
3704-156  11/22/2019
3732-231  11/15/2019
5515-004  10/23/2019
>>> f = g.last()

>>> for r in f.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
...     print(getattr(r,'apn'), getattr(r,'date'))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'apn'

>>> for r in f.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
...     print(getattr(r,"apn"), getattr(r,"date"))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'apn'
```

What is the proper way to print this to a file?

eg.

```
apn, date
3704-156,11/22/2019
3732-231,11/15/2019
5515-004,10/23/2019
```

Comment: g.last().to_csv() should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv("n2.txt")
g = df.groupby('apn').last()
print(g.to_csv())
```

Should work as you wish.

If you type `g.to_csv()` into your console, it returns a string starts with `'apn,data,\r\n...'`. And `print` function will start a new line when come across `'\r\n'`, which finally gives output as your wish.

Comment: Becasue I explain it detaily and provide a code snippet. `to_csv` only gives a csv format without any printout! We should print it out, which is op's question. To answer a question, we should not only gives a `function`, we should explain `what`, `how` and even `why`, which helps others more and show our respect!

Comment: OK, not repeated code from question first, but now solution was changed for it.

Comment: hmmm, maybe you miss last question `What is the proper way to print this to a file?`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be changed:

```
df = pd.read_csv("n2.txt")
g = df.groupby('apn')
f = g.last()
```

Use [`Series.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) because output of `f` is pandas `Series`:

```
f.to_csv(file)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with convert `index` to 2 columns `DataFrame`:

```
f.reset_index().to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Or use solution with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("n2.txt")
df = df.drop_duplicates('apn', keep='last')
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

In your solution use `Index` for select `index` of `Series`:

```
for r in f.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    print(getattr(r,'Index'), getattr(r,'date'))
3704-156 11/22/2019
3732-231 11/15/2019
5515-004 10/23/2019
```